# Where to connect Phantom 410 case cables?

Tags: cable, case

I have NZXT Phantom 410 case, I have connected mostly all the case cables except for those in the image :

[cables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEXGF.jpg)

I have looked in the case Manual but they don't say anything about these cables, even whats the name or what they do or where to connect them, So hopefully someone here tells me these information because thats my first PC build.

Thanks.

Comment: Those look like splitters for 3 pin fans.

Comment: So I don't need to connect them anywhere ? I have connected the 4pin molex which I believe is the fan power cable

Comment: I don't think you'll need to.  Some fans use a 3 pin connector that would plug into a spot on the Motherboard or into a splitter so you can run more than one fan off that same connection point on the motherboard.  It's likely the manufacturer of your case provided those cables for if you needed them.

Comment: Okay thanks, if you are sure of that just post it as an answer and after I run the PC and try I'll mark it as an answer

Comment: Before that, could you post another picture of the other end of the cable? A few more pictures of the cable would definitely help me. Or is that already being shown in the picture? It's a little hard to tell

Comment: actually I don't know where exactly the other end, because  the all of the case cables are hidden in side the case skeleton and only the connectors are there as shown, and here is another another image: https://s10.postimg.org/im8zzi3ix/image.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after seeing the picture in the last comment, I'm confident that that is a 3 pin fan splitter. In this case, the manufacture seems to give you the ability to wire fans to one location that is stowed away with where the rest of the wires go (kind of a nice feature!).

At first I did not realize that they were part of the rest of the wires that came with the case.  I thought they were separate pieces, like one of these:

[3 pin fan splitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6FEN.jpg)